# jQuery if input text equals var do something

Tags: jquery, input, var, attr

I have a form that calculates the sum of several input values (checkboxes and dropdowns - not user entered values). At the bottom of the form I have a "Discount Code" box, I want to be able to enter a code and it takes a set amount off the total.

With my code I am trying to say, if text entered = discount code, change the value of the input to 50. Here is what I have so far

```
var discountCode = 'DISTR50';
var codeEntered = $("input[name='discount']");

 if (discountCode = codeEntered) {
    $('#discount input').attr('value',50);
 }
```

and for the html:

```
<input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" class="txt"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
    $('input#discount').attr('value',50);
 }
```

Do not use = use either == or better ===

Also instead of using attr you can simple use val as suggested below and use `input#discount` as the correct selector and use val() to get the value

```
var discountCode = 'DISTR50';
var codeEntered = $("input[name='discount']").val();

 if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
    $('input#discount').val('50');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

= is assignment, == or === is to check if something is equal to the other.

What is it you want to fetch from $("input[name='discount']")? Cause this will give you a jquery object, try $("input[name='dicount']").val(); to fetch value, ie something like:

```
if('DISTR50' == $("input[name='discount']").val()){
    $("#discount input").attr("value", 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of minor issues...

```
var discountCode = 'DISTR50';
var codeEntered = $("#discount").val();

if (discountCode == codeEntered) {
    $('#discount').val(50);
}
```

Notice I added `.val()` to to get and set values of inputs, and changed the if statement to use `==` instead of `=`.

I also used the ID of the input element, as this will be quicker than looking for an input by name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var discountCode = 'DISTR50';
var codeEntered = $("input[name='discount']");

 if (discountCode === codeEntered) {
    $('#discount').val('50');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare object with values

You need to do like this:

```
var discountCode = 'DISTR50';
var codeEntered = $("input[name='discount']").val(); <-- .val()
```

The code you are writing returns object in `codeEntered` variable, you should use `.val()` to get the value of that object.

And for the comparision use `==` or `===` (for strict comparison)